# (Node.js/Express.js) Error: Schema hasn't been registered for model "document"

Tags: mongodb, node.js, express

I was trying to work my way through the nodepad tutorial on Dailyjs.com (found [here](http://dailyjs.com/2010/11/08/node-tutorial-2/)). I eventually came to halt when I received this upon trying to execute(after step 2 of tut):

```
Error: Schema hasn't been registered for model "Document".
Use Mongoose.define(name, schema)
    at Mongoose.model     (/usr/local/lib/node/.npm/mongoose/1.0.16/package/lib/mongoose/index.js:138:13)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/root/Repos/nodepad/models.js:3:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:374:26)
    at Object..js (module.js:380:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:306:31)
    at Function._load (module.js:272:10)
    at require (module.js:318:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/root/Repos/nodepad/app.js:10:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:374:26)
    at Object..js (module.js:380:10)
```

Mostly I'm a complete noob here, so what I really need is not so much a "do this to make it work" answer, but if you don't mind, an explanation as to what the actual cause of this error is.  I can post the actual code I have now if needed, and apologize if this is some agonizingly simple issue.

models.js:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.model('Document', {
    properties: ['title', 'data', 'tags'],
    indexes:    ['title']
});

exports.Document = function(db) {
    return db.model('Document');
};
```

Comment: could you please post the part of the code where you define your mongoose models?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Since Mongoose 1.0 you have to define your models in a different way. To see that applied to nodepad, i recommend reading up on the [source of nodepad](https://github.com/alexyoung/nodepad) (especially the file `models.js`).

Example:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
  Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var User = new Schema({
  email: {
    type: String,
    index: { unique: true }
  },
  name: String,
  lastseen: Date,
  isonline: Boolean,
  hashed_password: String,
  salt: String
});

mongoose.model('User', User);
```

Sadly, the 'older' blogposts of the (absolutely awesome) DailyJS tutorial are kind of outdated. Alex Youg did post some follow-up posts to migrate the existing tutorial to Mongoose 1.0 (which introduced really heavy API changes), see [here](http://dailyjs.com/2011/02/07/node-tutorial-12/).

Comment: I thought it might be a version difference, but being just a beginner it's hard to nail these things down(not sure how to even check the current version of modules). That gets me out of my rut and provides some forward momentum though. Thanks for the quick reply!